# Reify only one has_many :through association with PaperTrail?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord, paper-trail-gem

I'm using the [paper_trail-association_tracking gem](https://github.com/westonganger/paper_trail-association_tracking) to save PaperTrail versions for AR associations. I have a model, let's call it User, that has many Groups and has many Skills. Both of these associations have join tables (`user_groups` and `user_skills`). So my User model has two `has_many :through` associations. All of the models (User, Group, Skill, UserSkill, UserGroup) have PaperTrail enabled on them.

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_paper_trail

  has_many :groups, through: user_groups
  has_many :user_groups

  has_many :skills, through: user_skills
  has_many :user_skills
end
```

Say I want to `reify` an earlier version of the User model, along with their Skills (`user_skills` records), but not revert to an earlier version of the user's Groups (`user_groups`). The code looks something like this:

```rb
me = User.find(1)
older_me = me.versions.last.reify(has_many: true)
older_me.save
```

This will reify both UserGroups and UserSkills for this User, but I want it to reify just UserSkills. It seems the gem will reify all associations automatically, based on this [source code](https://github.com/westonganger/paper_trail-association_tracking/blob/6a1cd2f1db58383d5b84477bb3ae2ac1a1acbc15/lib/paper_trail_association_tracking/reifier.rb#L27) I looked through.

So is there a way to specify which association I want to be reified? Or is it not best practices to do this? For my use case, I can't see a problem with this unless the user itself was actually deleted or something like that.

Sorry my models here sound kinda weird, I tried to use something generic and simplified, my real use case and models are a bit complex but this question demonstrates the bottom line of my issue.

Comment: I think your review of the PT-AT source is correct. There seems to be no PT-AT feature that does what you want, as of today, 2019-10-24.

Comment: Maybe you can use a temporary variable `x` to remember the user's groups and when the `reify` is done, set `user.user_groups = x`?

Comment: @JaredBeck ah ok. Yeah that's essentially what I ended up doing to get around it but I'll leave this question open. Sounds like it might end up being more of a feature request.